# Perl: Trouble with Exporter

Tags: perl, exporter

Module: ***`./FOO/BAR/Foobar.pm`***

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Foobar;
   our($VERSION , @ISA , @EXPORT , @EXPORT_OK , %EXPORT_TAGS , $FOO);
   BEGIN {
      require Exporter;
      @ISA       = qw(Exporter);
      @EXPORT_OK = qw(&foo);
   }

   sub foo {
      print "Loaded\n";
      $FOO = q{some val};
   }

1;
```

Program: ***`./Caller.pl`***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use FOO::BAR::Foobar qw/foo/;

   Foobar::foo();  # works
   foo();          # errors out - can't find &main::foo
```

---

I'd list all the things I've tried, but there are a lot - as you can see I have more global Foobar globals than that listed.  I've removed the BEGIN and done some other things as suggested in [older] posts on PerlMonks.

I think I read somewhere once that if the package name is the same name as the module name, Exporter works a certain way by default.  I don't know if putting the module in a sub-directory could have changed that behavior(?).  However, I'm eager to see how I've screwed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the module is located in FOO/BAR/Foobar.pm, then the package name should be `FOO::BAR::Foobar`.

I would also remove the `&` sign from the @EXPORT_OK array.

Comment: +1 --- it seems my suspicions had some merit. Is there an alternative to renaming the package?

Comment: I answered the question I had above (in comment).  I'll accept this as the answer - though, I'd still like to find some resource on importing a different package's variables/functions

Answer (score 4):

In addition to choroba's answer I found this [post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t908972-dose-package-name-has-to-be-the-same-as-the-filename-for-oo.html) by [Sherm Pendley](http://shermspace.blogspot.com/), which I think is the same post I read years ago:

> In a non-OO module that exports functions, they have to be the same for
>   Exporter to do its thing. When you use() a module - let's call it "Foo",
>   the following steps are basically what happens:
>
> ```
> BEGIN {
>    require Foo;
>    import Foo qw(args);
> }
> ```
>
> The second step is optional - if there's no import() function in module
>   Foo, the use() will still succeed.
>
> Now, let's suppose that package Bar is in Foo.pm. Foo.pm is compiled by
>   the require() with no problems. Because its code is in package Bar, the
>   import() function, explicitly declared or inherited from Exporter, is
>   compiled into that package too.
>
> But the use() still tries to call an import() function in package
>   Foo. Worse, because import() is optional it will *silently* fail. The
>   only clue the user will get that something has gone wrong, is that none
>   of the functions declared in package Bar will be usable without a fully-
>   specified package name, i.e. Bar::baz(), because the import() failed to
>   create aliases for them in the current package.
>
> Other things can depend on the filename = package convention too. Take
>   perldoc, for example. If a user of your module runs "perldoc Foo" to get
>   your module's docs, it will read the docs found in Foo.pm. The user's
>   going to be confused if those docs describe a package named "Bar."
>
> Even if your module is "pure" OO and doesn't export anything, following
>   the established convention helps avoid confusion - imagine a maintenance
>   programmer looking at your script a year from now, and seeing this:
>
> ```
> use Foo;
> my $bar = Bar->new();
> ```
>
> It's not very intuitive to see a class Bar defined in Foo.pm.
>
> So no, it's not required in theory. But the convention of naming them
>   the same is followed so widely, that in practice it's really more or
>   less required.

---

So, it seems if you have multiple packages per module, only the one that share the same name as the file can export its variables/functions.  I suspect you could get it to work if you were to create your own import function for the other packages (?).

Anyhow, in my example, if I didn't want to call the *package* the whole hierarchy tree, I could set the lib:

```
use lib './FOO/BAR';
use Foobar qw/foo/;   # instead of "use FOO::BAR::Foobar"
```

This would mean I could still have `Foobar.pm` and inside it `package Foobar` instead of `package FOO::BAR::Foobar`